VBA copy and paste a range multiple times based on cell value
I'm trying to copy and paste a range of cells multiple times based on the number that is listed in another cell (up to 3 times). So If B1 = 2 then I want to copy and paste A2:C11 into A13:C22.If B1 = 3 then copy and paste A2:C11 into A13:C22 AND A24:C33.If B1 = 4 then copy and paste A2:C11 into A13:C22 AND A24:C33 AND A35:C44.
I'm very new to VBA so I appreciate any help!! Thank you!!

Haven't tried anything as I don't really know where to begin.

Sorry, mistyped. Yes, I mean B1.

Sub CopyBlock()
    Dim rng As Range, n As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' sheet name
        .Rows("13:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
        Set rng = .Range("A2:C11")
        For n = 1 To .Range("B1").Value - 1
           rng.Copy rng.Offset(n * (rng.Rows.Count + 1))
        Next
        MsgBox n - 1 & " blocks copied", vbInformation
    End With
End Sub


This worked! Thank you!

Could I add something that removes extra copied blocks if I change the B1 number? For example, changing it from 4 to 2 will remove the 2 extra copied blocks?

@stella Is it ok to delete all the rows below 12 and recreate the first block

Yes, all the rows can be deleted below 12

@stella add line .Rows("13:" & .Rows.Count).Delete - see update

Awesome! That worked! Thank you so much!
